# How can I fix the "invalid syntax" error?

Tags: python, syntax

This is the whole program. I have written where the problem occurs on my screen. You can get the original copy from [here](http://inventwithpython.com/dragon.py) (Chapter 6, Dragon Realm)

```
import random
import time

def displayIntro():
    print('You are in a land full of dragons. In front of you,')
    print('you see two caves. In one cave, the dragon is friendly')
    print('and will share his treasure with you. The goblin')
    print('is greedy and wants to loot you on sight.')
    print()

def chooseCave():
    cave = ''
    while cave != '1' and cave != '2':
        print('Which cave will you go into? (1 or 2)')
        cave = input()

    return cave

def checkCave(chosenCave):
    print('You approach the cave...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('It is dark and spooky...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('The goblin sees you and tells you too hand over your stuff')
    time.sleep(2)
    print("oh! I forgot you are an apprentice looking Merlin you can use ur magic on him")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("You can choose betweeen, fire, water, air or earth")
    print()
    time.sleep(2)

    friendlyCave = random.randint(1, 2)

    if chosenCave == str(friendlyCave):
         print('Gives you his treasure!')
    else:
         print('Takes your stuff and run')
def spell(magic):
```

This is about where i think the problem occurs.

```
    if magic == 'air' or magic == 'fire' or magic == 'water' or magic == 'earth' #This is where the problem occurs I think it is because of some prior codes
def choosespell(maguc)#choose between spells
if magic == 'air':
    print('you blew the goblin away')
    elif magic == 'fire':
        print('you burned the goblin to death')
        elif magic == 'water':
            print('the goblin drowned to death')
            elif magic  == 'earth':
                print('The veins chocked him to death')
magic = input()
playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain == 'yes' or playAgain == 'y':

    displayIntro()

    caveNumber = chooseCave()

    checkCave(caveNumber)

    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playAgain = input()
```

Comment: Wrong indentions en masse. You know that leading spaces play a crucial role in Python?

Comment: You *think* that's where the problem occurs? Have you checked the line number mentioned in the error message?

Comment: The second code block contains so many errors that it's very hard to know if you just done a bad job inserting the text in the question, or if that's really the code you have. Please make sure that the code in the question is the same as the code in your editor.
As Matthias said; indentation in python is very important!

Answer (score 4):

You do **not** seem to have grasped the basics of python syntax and semantics. *I suggest you stop trying to read code,* without first having at least some basic knowledge of  the language syntax, because all you are going to get is confused.

In my honest opinion, try to read a book in python first. Two great (and free ones are) [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) and [Learn Python the Hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing a colon after the function definition choosespell. Also magic is misspelled. Try changing it to:

> def choosespell(magic): #choose between spells

Comment: The line just above that misses a colon too, and a statement to go after it.